# Query Performance: single column vs multiple column

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, query-optimization

Which table structure is better among below 2?

[image]

OR

[image]

in first query i use `LIKE` operator in query.
In second i use `AND` operator.

Does first table design has any advantages over second on selecting data?
On what situation i need to decide between first table structure and second one?

Comment: The first table contains raw, unformatted, unnormalized data.  It will be costly to query and even more costly to maintain.  I give two thumbs up to the second table.

Comment: second structure is way better
maybe later you need to filter on Type or Currency

Comment: select * from table 1 where measurement_name like '%Type=ODO Currency=EUR%';                                                                                              Or                                                                                                                      Select * from table2 where type='ODO' and Currency = 'EUR' ;                       Which workes faster?

Comment: second select will be faster

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one would be better if you never needed to work with the `Type` or the `Currency` attributes in any way and you used allways only the whole text stored as `MEASUREMENT_NAME`.

If you plan to work with the values of the `Type` or the `Currency` attributes separately, like using their values in where conditions etc., the second option will allways be a better choice.

You can also eventually create a combined structure containing both the whole text `MEASUREMENT_NAME` and separated values `Type` & `Currency` for filtering purposes. This would take more space on disk and would not be optimized, but the whole text or `MEASUREMENT_NAME` can in the future also eventually contain atributes that are now unknown to you. That could be the reason for storing `MEASUREMENT_NAME` in the raw format.

In case that the attribute `MEASUREMENT_NAME` is not something you get from external sources, but it is a data structure made by yourself and you seek a way how to store records with flexible (changing) structure, you better store it as JSON or XML data, Oracle has [built in functions for JSON data](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6248).

I also recommend to use linked tables for `Type` or `Currency` values, so that the main table contains only ID link as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Second table obviously have advantages over first. If you have to query type or currency from first table, you might have to use right, left or any other functions.
Also if you align keys/constraints for second table, follows 2nd normal form.